# Is Endpoint with custom port does not supported by Guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I am trying to hit API endpoint from my Laravel 5.8.* project.
I am using Guzzle 6.0 with PHP version 7.1.3.

When I run my project in local machine, I get the API response successfully.

But after uploading the project to liver server, I could not get the API response.

I get the response "**cURL error 7: Failed to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx port 3333: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)**".

The code that I use is as follows.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3333/api/getrecords', [
    'tbl' => ['user', 'activity']
]);
echo $res->getMessage();
```

The same code is working perfectly in local machine but not in live server.

My Server is Linux server.

Comment: Have you made sure that the port isn't closed on the server?

Comment: Which Server do I check the port status on API server or on live Laravel Project hosted server? Also I am getting the response from API on my local machine but not on live server.

Comment: Try simple `file_get_contents('http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3333/api/getrecords')`. If it fails as well then the problem is in the server, not in guzzle. Also there is no parameter `tbl`, it looks like a mistake.

Comment: @Stalinko, I did use the PHP Curl and get the same response of "cUrl Error 7, Connection refused". So should I check the API hosted server port whether it is enabled to not?? One thing, I do not understand is that if why is it working in my local server but not in live server?

Comment: @SarojShrestha it works on your local machine because it is allowed to connect to that remote address, while your server has some settings which don't let it go. Maybe this is firewall or something else. If you have a linux-based OS then try in command line `curl http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3333/api/getrecords` if it doesn't work then the problem is in server configuration. If it works then the problem in PHP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any proxy configured in your server? If so, try to set a proxy in your guzzle request: [Guzzle proxy docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#proxy)

Basically, you have to set an array with the proxy.

```
$client->request('GET', '/', ['proxy' => 'tcp://localhost:8125']);
```

Comment: I am still getting same error even after adding the proxy params as well.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to make request using port 3333. This port 3333 needs to be open in your machine only then you will be able to make request from this port.